# Computed column definition is null

Tags: sql-server

(A.) The below is the condition of "d_no" column in table test. Here you can see that it is a computed column and its definition is NULL.So I want to know that how this case is possible to generate? I am unable to create a computed column with NULL definition.

> table name : test 
>  column name : d_no 
>  is_nullable : 1
>   
>  definition : NULL 
>  is_computed : 1

This case is for SQL Server 2012 (11.0.6523) version.

(B.) Scenario : 
There is "User1" who is real database owner(own database). There is another user "User2". The User2 has some permissions to access the database of User1, like SELECT or get DDL. 
When I login with User2 and tried to get CREATE query for the table which has a column as Computed Column. For that table we are not getting computed column definition in the result query. 
We are getting xyz (numeric (18,0) null)

So is it possible that there also same permission issue is occur which may result null in previous case(A)?

Comment: Please script out the `CREATE TABLE` and add it to your question.

Comment: Hello Martin, we don't have this permission as we are the second user.

Comment: So that is why you are seeing NULL then - as the answer states.

Comment: How can I get only NULL value in definition field rather (CONVERT([int],NULL,0))......

Answer (score 3):

You can't get null definition.Even creating computed column as null,won't change the defintion to null..

```
create table dbo.t4
(
id int null,
idplus as cast(null as int)
)

select definition 
from sys.computed_columns
```

**Output:**

```
(CONVERT([int],NULL,0))
```

You are seeing `NULL` defintion due to permissions issue..

Below is [what MSDN has to say](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191507(v=sql.105).aspx) about this..

> The rules for viewing the Transact-SQL source code of database objects are stricter than for viewing metadata.
>
> To see the Transact-SQL definition of an object, ***a user must either own the object or have been granted one of the following permissions on the object***:
>
> CONTROL
> ALTER
> TAKE OWNERSHIP
> VIEW DEFINITION

Same is the case with below views as well,if you don't have permissions,Definition would be null..

[image]

Comment: Sir, I tried your suggestion but still I get   (CONVERT([int],NULL,0))  value in my DEFINITION field, I deny all CONTROL
ALTER
TAKE OWNERSHIP
VIEW DEFINITION permissions as per your answer. I want to get NULL value in DEFINITION field. How I can able to do that

Comment: you will be needing permissions i specified in answer to view definition,Grant those permissions to your login and you will be able to see it

Comment: Sir plz specify that exactly on which object(database, table, user or particular column) I have to apply or deny these permissions.

Comment: grant on table and see

Comment: The issue is that I can't get NULL definition in definition field. According to this table query I get (CONVERT([int],NULL,0)) but I want to get only NULL value.

Comment: you can't get null definition,issue you are seeing is due to permissions

Comment: thanks for ur help. I get it now. Yes it was a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

a) If the user is not the table owner of myTable and has been granted only SELECT permission on the table, when the user accesses the following catalog views, the definition columns are NULL.

Mean a user is having only select (datareader) permission instead dbowner . Then login with that user and check the definition for the computed column.

select definition 
from sys.computed_columns

It gives you NULL value in definition field.

b) If you want to get the definition of computed column in the definition field for the same user as above, who have only SELECT permission, then grant the VIEW DEFINITION permission for the particular object (table having computed column)
via user.

Then again login with that user and run the query to see definition value. That time it will show you actual definition of computed column in definition field.